# SSRS report combine data sources and generate csv

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am new to ssrs. I have a report that gets data from two databases. I can create two datasets that connect to two different databases. The databases are third party and I cannot create stored procedures on the databases. My issue is that I have to combine the data from the two queries.

Please help me with this issue or point me to locations where I can find answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would accomplish this in SSRS. Are you looking to get the data out in structured report format? Or just in a raw data format? If it is the latter, I would recommend taking a look at SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). Lots of tools for manipulating data from multiple data sources and outputting in many different ways.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Im cannot use ssis. Im trying to create a report and setup an email subscription to email the report as csv. Im still researching how to remove the header in csv. I tried changin Noheader to true in hte config file but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SQL Server Reporting Services Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) on MSDN.

Or Google or Bing for "Reporting Services Tutorial" - I guarantee you'll get thousands of hits......

What you need to do is pretty basic - just drag & drop those columns / fields you need onto your report.....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did combine the datasources on my report.
I used two tables to output the results on the report but I need to extract the report as csv. The problem...the header repeats for each datasource. I googled and changed the Noheader xml node in hte config file, but it did not work. I ended up changin the sql to union all. Im still researching how to remove the header of the report when I export it to csv.

Answer (score 0):

are the databases on the same server?  if so, i would cheat and use a union all to join the data on the server side in your data set.  if you are using a stored procedure use union all in the stored procedure.  if you're doing an ad hoc query in the data set (which is bad practice, but whatever) put a union all in there.

Answer (score 0):

To remove anything from a report when exporting it, you must select the textbox and goto properties.  Find the DataElementOutput and set it to No Output.